# Seemingly lagged results of AR(1) prediction

Tags: python, python-2.7, statsmodels

I am using `statsmodels` to attempt an AR(1) regression of some data. An extract of my code is:

```
ar_model = tsa.AR(data).fit(1)
ar_model.predict(start='20151015', end='20151115').plot()
data['20151015':'20151115'].plot(style='--')
```

The picture below shows part of the data (blue dashed) and the fit (red solid). It appears that my prediction reproduces some features of the data, but the results are delayed by one (e.g. the big spike is on the 7th of November in the data, 8th of November in the predictions). The same happens at other dates. Am I doing something wrong?

In case anyone would like to reproduce my results, I'll try to post a link to it in an answer (can't do here, need 10 reputation to post 2 links)

Data (blue dashed) and the fit (red solid).

[image]

Bonus question: I have to print my fit parameters and discovered online that I can use `ar_model.params`, and it works. However, I haven't seen this option in the [documentation](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.ar_model.AR.fit.html#statsmodels.tsa.ar_model.AR.fit).

I am also finding it hard to understand how some other features work from the documentation. (I am fairly new to Python, I used to work with Mathematica.) Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ab7xtab3rddcao2/data.txt?dl=0

Comment: This lagged effect in the forecast is a consequence of an AR process. AR(1) uses only the value from the previous period to forcast, i.e. one-period ahead prediction will be close to observed value in previous period if the AR coefficient is large.